# curiosity about RTTI raw_name()

Tags: c++, visual-studio, rtti, typeinfo

Looking at the C++ RTTI and type_info class sometimes I find the description of a  method called `raw_name()` that is used to return the demangled name of a class. I cannot find any implementation in g++ but only the method `name()`. Do you know whether that is an implementation specific only for Visual Studio/MS and and whether is part of the C++ standard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is **implementation specific**, `type_info` is defined in the standard at:

**C++03 Standard: 18.7.1 Class type_info:**

```
namespace std {
class type_info {
public:
virtual ~type_info();
bool operator==(const type_info& rhs) const noexcept;
bool operator!=(const type_info& rhs) const noexcept;
bool before(const type_info& rhs) const noexcept;
size_t hash_code() const noexcept;
const char* name() const noexcept;
type_info(const type_info& rhs) = delete; // cannot be copied
type_info& operator=(const type_info& rhs) = delete; // cannot be copied
};
}
```

As you see `raw_data` is **not** a standard defined class member.

Comment: oops a typo, the citation is from C++11 not C++03.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification!Most of the times I found raw_name() in MSDN pages ( and not only )!

Answer (score 3):

A quick Google will show you that `raw_name()` is only documented by Microsoft.  It's not part of C++.